# How to add click event and if condition together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to perform some task based on 2 conditions on page load.
1) If a button is clicked or
2) If condition becomes true

so can I combine this two events into one?

```
  if(x== true) || button.click(function(e){
..  
  perform task...       
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean if the condition becomes true after the initialisation code for the page has finished executing? How does the condition become true? As a result of code you're calling?

Comment: I am passing some variable from controller. If that is true or if button is clicked then perform some operation.

Comment: This is not how you're supposed to handle events... You should have 1 handler for click, calling a method, and then you're free to call the same method on any consition you need, whenever you need it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var perform_task = function() {
    ....
}

if(x == true) perform_task();

button.click(function(er) { perform_task(); }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The only missing piece is if you want the event to fire when X becomes true.  In that case you'd want to fire the event when any code sets x to true (and potentially create some sort of setter that fires the event if x is changed in many places).

Answer (score 3):

try this?

```
button.click(function(){
   if(x == true){
       /* do something */
   }
});
```

Comment: but what if x== true & I did not click the button? it's or condition where if x == true or button is clicked then do something. Will that work then?

Answer (score 0):

```
var flag = false;

$("button").click(function() { 

       flag = true;
});

 if((x== true) || flag ){

     // do here
}
```

Comment: after clicking on button, will it go to if condition automatically?